# Error while trying to findNearLocation with Pageable in MongoDB and Spring

Tags: java, spring, geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

I'm facing a strange error when I try to execute a find near with pageable in Mongodb and spring boot. My collection have 5 stores. When I call the method with the params: *Page 0* and *Page Size of 5 or below* it works. But when I call it with a PageSize equals or greather than the total of stores I get this error. I noticed that the error occurs when the spring data mongo calls the method doCount internally but I have no idea what is wrong.

Below is my code and the error:

----- Models ----

```
@Document("stores")
@Getter
@Setter
@TypeAlias("Store")
@ToString(of = {"id", "name"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Store {
    
    public static final String DOCUMENT_INDEX_NAME = "documentIndex";
    public static final int MIN_SIZE_DOCUMENT = 14;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE_DOCUMENT = MIN_SIZE_DOCUMENT;
    public static final int MIN_SIZE_NAME = 3;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE_NAME = 200;
    
    public Store() {
        this.metaInf = new MetaInf();
    }
    
    public Store(String document, String name) {
        this();
        this.document = document;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    @CNPJ(message = "{validation.store.document.cnpj}")
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.store.document.notnull}")
    @Size(message = "{validation.store.document.size}", min = MIN_SIZE_DOCUMENT, max = MAX_SIZE_DOCUMENT)
    @Pattern(message = "{validation.store.document.pattern}", regexp = "\\d{" + MIN_SIZE_DOCUMENT + "}")
    @Indexed(unique = true, name = DOCUMENT_INDEX_NAME)
    @Field(name = "document")
    private String document;
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.store.name.notnull}")
    @Size(message = "{validation.store.name.size}", min = MIN_SIZE_NAME, max = MAX_SIZE_NAME)
    @Field(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Field(name = "address")
    private Address address;
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.default.metainf.notnull}")
    @Field(name = "metaInf")
    private MetaInf metaInf;
    
}



@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(of = {"street", "number", "district", "city", "state"})
public class Address {
    
    public static final String LOCATION_INDEX_NAME = "locationIndex";

    @Field(name = "street")
    private String street;
    @Field(name = "number")
    private String number;
    @Field(name = "district")
    private String district;
    @Field(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Field(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Field(name = "location")
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(name = LOCATION_INDEX_NAME, type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPoint location;
    
}
```

------ Repository Method (This repository extends *MongoRepository*)------

```
GeoPage<Store> findByAddressLocationNear(Point point, Distance distance, Pageable pageable);
```

----- Service -----

```
    @Override
    public GeoPage<Store> findNearest(Point point, Distance distance, Pageable pageable) {
            LOG.debug("Searching nearests from {} within distance {}, pageable: {}", point, distance, pageable);
            return storeRepository.findByAddressLocationNear(point, distance, pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public GeoPage<StoreDTO> findNearestDtos(Point point, Distance distance, Pageable pageable) {
        return modelMapper.map(findNearest(point, distance, pageable), new TypeToken<GeoPage<StoreDTO>>() {}.getType());
    }
```

----- Controller -----

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @GetMapping("/nearest")
    public ResponseEntity<Response<GeoPageResponse<StoreDTO>, String>> findNearest(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User user
            , @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) FindNearestDTO dto) {
        LOG.info("Searching nearest Stores, dto {}", dto);
        GeoPage<StoreDTO> page = storeService.findNearestDtos(dto.getPointsAsGeoJsonPoint(), dto.getGeoDistance(), dto.getPageable());
        return Response.ok(new GeoPageResponse<>(page));
    }
```

----- ERROR -----

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'Point must only contain numeric elements' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Point must only contain numeric elements", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:358) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:279) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:100) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:490) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:110) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:345) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:336) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommandWithConnection(CommandOperationHelper.java:222) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper$5.call(CommandOperationHelper.java:208) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:583) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AggregateOperationImpl.execute(AggregateOperationImpl.java:189) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AggregateOperation.execute(AggregateOperation.java:300) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:254) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:61) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:170) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCount(MongoCollectionImpl.java:223) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.countDocuments(MongoCollectionImpl.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$doCount$14(MongoTemplate.java:1131) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:553) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 131 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I solved the problem. In my controller I was passing a `GeoJsonPoint` as parameter. When I changed to a `Point` it worked.

---- Before ----

```
GeoPage<StoreDTO> page = storeService.findNearestDtos(dto.getPointsAsGeoJsonPoint(), dto.getGeoDistance(), dto.getPageable());
```

----- After -----

```
GeoPage<StoreDTO> page = storeService.findNearestDtos(dto.getPointsAsPoint(), dto.getGeoDistance(), dto.getPageable());
```